# Strange Behavior of NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, numerics

I am trying to evaluate the following ODE numerically:

```
NDSolve[(2 + Sqrt[2] +s^2 -(-2 + Sqrt[2]) s^4 + s^6) /(1 + s^2)^2 yy[s] -(1 - s^2)^2 yy''[s] == 0 && 
        yy[-1] == 0 &&   yy'[-1] == 1, yy[s], {s, -1, 1}]
```

and I surprisingly get the following error:

```
Power::infy: "Infinite expression 1/0.^2 encountered."
Infinity::indet: "Indeterminate expression 0.\ ComplexInfinity encountered."
NDSolve::ndnum: "Encountered non-numerical value for a derivative at s == -1.`."
```

One can verify directly that no infinities should appear at `s=-1`:

```
D[(2 + Sqrt[2] + s^2 - (-2 + Sqrt[2]) s^4 + s^6)/(1 + s^2)^2, s] /.  s -> -1

gives: 3 + 1/4 (-8 + 4 (-2 + Sqrt[2]))
```

But apparently, the ODE solver automatically divides by the factor in front of the `yy''[s]` term before computation. in this case we indeed find a singular

```
D[-(2 + Sqrt[2] + s^2 - (-2 + Sqrt[2]) s^4 + s^6)/((1 + s^2)^2 (1 - s^2)^2), s] /. s -> -1
```

Clearly, if one does not divide by the factor of the kinetic term, the ODE is well defined on the whole interval including the boundaries. Why does the solver divide? What can I do to prevent this? Or maybe there is some workaround?

Comment: It cannot solve for `yy''[s]` at `s == -1`, since the coefficient vanishes.  (At a naive level, it cannot then approximate the next value of `yy'[s]` for `s` a little greater than `-1`, etc.)  What is being detected is that `s == -1` is a singular point, and there are infinitely many solutions to this IVP (one for each value of `yy''[-1]` you care to assign).

Comment: Oh, yes, this makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: So, now that the problem with the ODE has been named, what would be an appropriate workaround? I can think of two: 1) Andrew's answer below, 2) Introduce a regulator `eps=10^-14` as a summand to the factor in front of `yy''[s]`. Are these any good?

Comment: BTW: The relevant information I want to acquire from the computation is the value of the solution at the right border `y[1]`

Comment: Do you know the values of `y[s]`, `y'[s]` at `s == 0` or some other point?  Or is knowing that `y` approaches infinity at `s == 1` enough?

Comment: The value of `y` at `s==1` is a functional determinant via Gel'fand Yaglom theorem. I will consider a ratio of this determinant with one of similar ODE. If I use the same regularization for both, the errors should cancel out.

Comment: Unfortunately, only initial values for `y` and `y'` are known.

Answer (score 2):

As an illustration of my initial comment, let's look at various starting points, following @Andrew's method:

```
sols = Table[
   NDSolveValue[(2 + Sqrt[2] + s^2 - (-2 + Sqrt[2]) s^4 + s^6)/(1 + s^2)^2 yy[s] -
       (1 - s^2)^2 yy''[s] == 0 && yy[start] == yy'[start] (start + 1) && yy'[start] == 1, 
    yy[s], {s, start, 1}], {start, -1 + 10^-9, -1 + 2 10^-8, 10^-9}];
Plot[sols, {s, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Output]

**Expanded comment**

I may have been hasty in asserting there are infinitely many solutions to the IVP in the question, although it looks plausible.  The point `s == -1` is a a regular singular point whose indicial equation has complex roots (if I didn't make a mistake).  Unfortunately I do not know much about such situations.  Certainly it should be clear that one cannot pick a particular starting point as a workaround.

Comment: Similarly, `sols = Table[
   NDSolveValue[(2 + Sqrt[2] + s^2 - (-2 + Sqrt[2]) s^4 + 
           s^6)/(1 + s^2)^2 yy[s] - ((1 - s^2)^2 + shift) yy''[s] == 
      0 && yy[-1] == 0 && yy'[-1] == 1, yy[s], {s, -1, 1}], {shift, 
    10^-9, 2 10^-8, 10^-9}];
Plot[sols, {s, 1 - 0.000001, 1}]` also displays a shift...

Comment: The problem here can be that the coefficient at $y''$ vanishes at $s=1$ too. And looking at the plot it seems not too implausible that $\lim_{s\to1-0}y(s)=+\infty$. Also Mma gives a warning that the solution may be stiff near $s=1$.

Comment: Yes, considering that the potential is symmetric it is clear that one should regularize both ends. e.g. `leftend = -1 + 10^-8;` and `rightend = 1 - 10^-8;`

Comment: @Kagaratsch But as far as I understood from the comments to the question the value of $y(1)$ is required.  If it is equal to $+\infty$, what else information of solution is needed?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround it is possible to step up a bit from the left end:

```
leftend = -1 + 10^-8; 
NDSolve[(2 + Sqrt[2] + s^2 - (-2 + Sqrt[2]) s^4 + s^6)/(1 + s^2)^2 yy[s]
- (1 - s^2)^2 yy''[s] == 0 && yy[leftend] == 0 && yy'[leftend] == 1, yy[s], 
{s, leftend, 1}][[1]]
```